# JMeter - Trouble sending HTTP request with POST variable?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to load test a java servlet that fetches records from an archive database.

The servlet works as follows:

- 1-Reads in post variables from HTTP header
- 2-Uses variables to query database
- 3-Returns XML

I have setup a test which I want to fire off HTTP requests with post variables however the test is not working, getting errors with J Meter.

**Screenshot 1 - Shows the structure of the test**
[image]

**Screenshot 2 - Shows the CSV file I am reading from**
[image]

I have placed the CSV file in the same folder that my test plan is saved in!

**Screenshot 3 - Shows the HTTP request**
[image]

**This is the error output:**

> Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1 Sample Start: 2012-11-20 10:35:27 GMT
>   Load time: 0 Latency: 0 Size in bytes: 1113 Headers size in bytes: 0
>   Body size in bytes: 1113 Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1 Response code:
>   Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException Response message:
>   Non HTTP response message: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address
>   at index 13:
>   http://[http://sophos1.testserver.co.uk/servlet/archive]:61061/
>
> Response headers:
>
> HTTPSampleResult fields: ContentType:  DataEncoding: null

**POST Request**

```
POST http://[http://sophos1.testserver.co.uk/servlet/archive]:61061/

POST data:


[no cookies]
```

**Returned DATA**

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 13: http://[http://sophos1.testserver.co.uk/servlet/archive]:61061/
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:232)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1064)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:426)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove `http://` from Server Name / IP field of your HTTP Request Sampler (that's pointed in [HTTP Request fields description](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)).

Look onto your generated POST request above in description:

```
POST Request
POST http://[http://sophos1.testserver.co.uk/servlet/archive]:61061/
```

Configure your HTTP Request as the following instead:

```
Server Name: sophos1.testserver.co.uk
Path: /servlet/archive
Implementation: Java
```

Comment: Thanks, so what is the difference between JAVA, HTTP3.1 and HTTP4 . Should I always use JAVA to be safe?

Comment: Its working now, however In the POST header its coming up as POST data:
**customerid=${id}**

Comment: 1. Look into [HTTP Request description](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - there are details for each implementation type with limitations mentioned. Using Java implementation is not the rule, but usage of HTTP4 can cause memory leak issue in case of load-test scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the post variable problem, it seems variables are case sensitive. I was using "id" instead of "ID"!

Comment: 2. You mean that the **${id}** is not expanded into corresponding value from csv upon sending request? If so then ensure that your CSV Data Set Config correctly extracts values from your csv-file into ${ID}.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is that you could leave the server name blank and set the path to

> http://sophos1.testserver.co.uk/servlet/archive

Comment: it's working with your solution but it's weird. We should be giving the IP on proper place. Same issue I have been seeing using Load runner

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any spaces in `ServerName` or `IP` field.

This gave me this error :

> Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in
>   authority at index 7:

When extra spaces were trimmed in the beginning, it worked well.