# Body-parse in Node.js not escaping new line chars in request body ? JSON

Tags: json, node.js, express, body-parser

I am creating a basic reverse proxy to pass on client requests to a remote server.

So I used body-parse with express.js for Node server to allow me to pass on the body.

However the JSON contains new line characters in it and extra braces.

**Client Side**

```
{
   "lastRefreshedDateTime" : "2015-05-24",
   "uid" : "1232141451"
}
```

**Server Side**

```
{
    '{
        \r\n"lastRefreshedDateTime": "2015-05-24",
        \r\n"uid
": "1234567124321"\r\n
    }\r\n': ''
}
```

**Node.js code**

```
        var express = require('express');
    var http = require('request');
    var path = require('path');
    var url = require("url");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); //this is required in express 4.x to output the contents of the client request body
    var app = express(); //start express server

    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser().json())
    // POST - getLocationData
    app.post('/getLocationData', function (request, response)
    {
        console.log("Request for /getLocationData");
        forwardRequest(request, response, "getLocationData", "POST", true);
    });


    app.listen(8080);

    function forwardRequest(request, response, serviceName, requestMethod, isJSON)
    {

        console.log("Making request to EAS for " + serviceName + ":");
        console.log(request.body); //json is fubar!

    };
```

I have tried removing the new line characters myself, but it still doesnt solve the problem of the additional braces and inverted commans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uglify the json on the client side. Strip out pretty printing before you send the string and it should eliminate the problem.

Use `JSON.stringify` on the client side and `JSON.parse` on the server side.

> edited to reflect comments

With reference to your question about [JMeter usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471521/jmeter-trouble-sending-http-request-with-post-variable), the problem you're having might actually be caused by Jackson or another Java JSON lib. **Setting your content-type encoding to UTF-8** generally completely resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks I tried that, it has solved the new line chars but not the additional brace

`{ '{"lastRefreshedDateTime" : "2015-04-01","uid" : ""}': '' }`

Comment: You don't need the external brace on the server side, JSON.parse does the trick and it's built-in, so more performant.

Comment: JSON.parse is failing , it is not valid JSON when it is at server side.

Comment: That's mind-blowing, I tested and it worked as expected for me. And you have no idea where those characters are coming from?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it is a problem with JMeter which I am using to send mock HTTP requests to my node server

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely be a potential cause, JMeter is Java IIRC. I checked the docs for JSON output just now and sure enough, the popular examples are often based on Jackson, which [is known to get weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175899/org-codehaus-jackson-jsonparseexception-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte-0xdf) with content-type encoding. (That's an extreme example but UTF-16, which is Java's default for strings, can be a bit weird too, ime.) Anyway, if it is JMeter / Jackson etc., setting your output as UTF-8 generally completely resolves the issue.

Comment: Just followed this tutorial, you have to explicitly set the encoding http://fabiouechi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/jmeter-posting-json-data-to-web-service.html

Answer (score -1):

You require `body-parser` but you never seem to use it..

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Put this just after the requires