# jmeter showing error when HTTP request is made

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am totally new to JMeter, when I tried to test a website.
The test result was like this

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-06-19 10:18:49 IST

Load time: 0

Connect Time: 0

Latency: 0

Size in bytes: 1176

Sent bytes:0

Headers size in bytes: 0

Body size in bytes: 1176

Sample Count: 1

Error Count: 1

Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException

Response message: Non HTTP response message: Expected closing bracket for IPv6
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter - Trouble sending HTTP request with POST variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471521/jmeter-trouble-sending-http-request-with-post-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like improper [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration, for instance you put some not supported character into "Server Name or IP" field. Well-behaved request should look like:

[image: JMeter HTTP Request configuration]

Another option is placing the full URL into "Path" field like

[image: JMeter full URL in Path]

However the best option will be just recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), this way JMeter will generate appropriate HTTP Request samplers which you will be able to replay with increased number of threads. See [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for comprehensive instructions.

Alternatively you can use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) - in this case you will not have to set up proxies and worry about SSL certificates.